# Wrong FQDN on Debian server

Tags: debian, hostname, fqdn

I have defined the server's FQDN and its alias in `/etc/hosts`:

```
X.X.X.X server1.example.com server1
```

However, the command `hostname --fqdn` only returns the alias (`server1`) and not the FQDN. Why is that?

Comment: Is the `127.0.1.1` entry still defined in hosts file with the short name?  Is your server using the `127.0.1.1` option?  By default debian will setup the /etc/hosts with an entry like `127.0.1.1 fully.quallified.tld shortname`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you changed `/etc/hostname` also? Did you restarted the network services after that change?

```
invoke-rc.d hostname.sh start
invoke-rc.d networking force-reload
invoke-rc.d network-manager force-reload
```

Without them, the server will still use the older one.

More info  [can be found here](https://wiki.debian.org/HowTo/ChangeHostname).

Comment: I've restarted the whole server and the hostname still gets reset back to the alias.

Comment: Have you changed `/etc/hostname` too?

Comment: Yes, I have already done that.